# Can we reorder elements when they are present inside different parents?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a simple section for which I want to re-order the elements in mobile.

In desktop, it looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this in mobile:

[image]

Here is what i have tried so far : JSFiddle [**live demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8pwqvaok/1/)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .flex-item1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .flex-item2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .flex-item3 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="top-content">
      <div class="col-lg-4" id="left-content">

        <h1 class="flex-item1"></h1>
        <div class="card-custom flex-item2">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8" id="right-content">
        <div class="flex-item3" canplay id="video-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The order property checks for the parent to have the flexbox model. But in your case the flexbox is set to row class and the order you are trying is not for the direct children.

Comment: Your structure does not allow that. Child of one div cannot take precedence in order over child of another div. 

That defeats the whole definition of `div` tag.

Comment: @HusainTezabwala so what do I need to do to get what I want??

Comment: @ManojKumar Hi, so what do I need to change in my codes to get what I want?

Comment: @user9964622 check my answer

Comment: you are using bootstrap right?

Comment: @StevenKuipers yes check the js fiddle I have provided

Comment: yeah i see now, always best to also use the bootstrap tag then as well

Comment: @zim the guy who made this question a duplicate can you provide the solution to my question using bootstrap??????  , am waiting

Comment: @StevenKuipers did u get a solution using bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of CSS Grid. I played around with a [Grid Generator](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/) here. Please use full screen mode to view the output.

**Note:** If anyone can reduce this code, please do since I just dived into CSS Grid.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wy3vzhoa/2/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  height: 500px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
  background: #00A2E8;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 3;
  background: #22b14c;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 5 / 5;
  background: #ED1C24;
}

@media ( max-width: 600px) {
  .div1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 5;
  }
  .div2 {
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 5;
  }
  .div3 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 5;
  }
}


/* Additional styles */

.container>div {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, How about compatibility with cross browsers?

Comment: Please check this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: yeah brother I am checking now  looking good ,

Comment: Thanks for that grid generator, wow amazing, I will be testing your solution with real data, I will be back for acceptance your answer

Comment: Manoj am struggling with grid sytem, here is my real data live demo , can you help me with you code to get this https://meed.audiencevideo.com/  ?

Comment: Hey, Can you open a new question? It may lead to endless discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `flexbox`, I did it with `table` tag

See if it suits you.

```css
.flex-item1 {
  background: skyblue;
  width;
  150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-item2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green
}

.flex-item3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .flex-item1,
  .flex-item2,
  .flex-item3 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="top-content">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="flex-item1">1</th>
          <th rowspan="2" class="flex-item3">3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="flex-item2">2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: my brother I gonna check this out , brb

Comment: Good solution if you want to use the table, I prefer grid or bootstrap solution with flexbox, because I have a lot of data will be added inside these columns, thanks for the help though, upvoted for the quick and simple solution

Comment: I was amazed when I myself opted for table over flexbox because it is oldschool. But the Grid based solution shared by Manoj is absolutely on point. That is the correct way to do it. I upvoted his answer myself ;)

Comment: Your right, I spent 3 hrs trying to figure out what the hell is going on :(

Answer (score 0):

use in col-xs-12 for the mobile version.

```
<section id="main-content">
           `enter code here`<div class="container">
                <div class="row" id="top-content">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="left-content">
                        <div class="row col-md-12>
                             <h1 class="flex-item1"></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row col-md-12>
                             <h1 class="flex-item2"></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12" id="right-content">
                            <div class="flex-item3" canplay id="video-block">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

</section>
```

css code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.flex-item1 {
    order: 1; 
   }
.flex-item2{
    order: 3;
}
.flex-item3{ 
  order: 2; 
}
}
```